# What actually is "tag score"?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I tried to make an (admittedly trivial) tag synonym for [esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) (has 1 question): [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming) (has 1 question...closed), but was rebuffed by the <strike>man</strike> system.  What is "tag score" if not what the tag's [top-users page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) says is "tag score"?

Does "this tag" in the error box refer to proposed synonym tag (my powers of English say no)?

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the synonym system only checks answerer tag score, not unlike how tag badges are awarded. Let me check.

Comment: I've always hated this system.  Unless these are now in /review, nobody sees 'em anyways.  Best to come straight to Meta.

Answer (score 4):

Those screenshots are poorly cropped. :P

Right above the place where you suggest synonyms in the top screenshot, it says:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. So, in your first screenshot the score refers to the net score of your answers in that tag.

Around the top users page in the bottom screenshot it looks like this:
[image: A screenshot showing "Top [esports] Askers above Nick T's section, with another section above that titled "Top [esports] Answerers, with Sorean's own score in it.]
That score next to your name is the net score of your questions in the tag. The score next to Sorean's name is the net score of his answers.

So, your problem is that you're looking at the score of your questions, while suggesting synonyms requires answer score.

Comment: Hey, yo, I'm not mistaken. Fancy that. ♪

Comment: The page should disambiguate "tag score" then `:P`